# Notification of instance state changes

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there any way to get a some logs out of AWS for things like "instance i-XXXX was started using ami-YYYY at 13:45.34 UTC" perhaps dumping a load of other information about the instance at the same time, e.g. az, key pair etc... Sure I can use cloud watch to monitor CPU usage, but I just want a simple log I can look at to see what amazon thinks happened in our cloud overnight.

Answer (score 0):

CloudTrail has all those infomation. You don't need to do anything:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Amazon has the [DescribeInstanceStatus](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstanceStatus.html) available. While I have no personal experience with it, it seems that you can get the status or events information for all instances with it. You can read about this on the [AWS blog](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/11/ec2-instance-status-monitoring.html).
More information about the detailed instances states can be found via the [DescribeInstances API call](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeInstances.html).

Comment: That call only shows running an very recently terminated instances. It doesnt show what I'm looking for: a history of what has run.